# Print weights when using Fast Artificial Neural Network Library

Tags: neural-network

I've got a problem which I imagine should be really simple but I can't seem to find anything on. I'm using the Fast Artificial Neural Network Library with the Python bindings and my network has been trained on some data and saved. So far so good.

The problem I'm having is I just can't seem to find any command to print the weighting for the various nodes. Could someone tell me what I need to use to do that please?

Comment: I was just waiting for the time limit to expire ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found it.

Just open the saved file with a text edit. Feeling a little silly now.